# How to play sounds on Cordova Android web app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating an android web app and it's simple thing. I have a button and I want it to play a sound when clicked. 
I'v searched a lot and actually no proper solution that could help me out.

I'm a newbie on this part and I really have no idea how I can play my sound.

any help will be appreciated.

Edited :
I installed media api on cordova : 
var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);

this is my html part :

```
<a href="#" id="applaud"><img src="images/applaud.png"></a></li>
```

this is the javascript part :

```
$("#applaud").bind('tap', function() {
            var media = new Media("lib/sounds/hooray.mp3", mediaSuccess);
            media.play();
        });
```

BTW I'm using jQuery Mobile for this application. Should I do anything else.

Thanks to those who answered my questions.

Update : 
I tried this code too ->

```
function playAudio(id) {
        var audioElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var url = audioElement.getAttribute('src');
        var my_media = new Media(url,
                // success callback
                 function () { alert("success"); },
                // error callback
                 function (err) { alert("error"); }
        );
               // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }
```

and then in my html it will be like this :

```
<a href="#" id="applaud" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/lib/sounds/hooray.mp3');"><img src="images/applaud.png"></a>
```

still nothing, I even revert my cordova to version 3.1 but nothing 
guys I really need help.

Comment: You need to provide more information. You mentioned in another comment that you are using Cordova. What have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: Did you installed the media plugin correctly? and used as documentation instructed? Provide some of your main code.

Comment: I added some codes on my first post.

Comment: @AtanuCSE do you have any manual for installing and using this plugin ? (except the one is on the phonegap website)

Comment: @Voicu could you help me outta here ?

Comment: nope I follwed the same documentation. One thing I didn't understand ` onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/lib/sounds/hooray.mp3');"` here you are sending the URL, and in method declaration you're catching ID!! `function playAudio(id)` the id has to be the url

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're developing an HTML web app. Try the [HTML5 `audio` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer , I tried this but when I build the app with cordova , the sounds wont play